# Metpy Brunt-Vaisala Frequency feature is returning with NaN

Tags: python, atmosphere, metpy

I am using metpy to calculate Brunt-Vaisala frequency and the code is running fine but my array of values is being returned as a bunch of NaN values. I have Pressure and temperature measured at the following elevations: 75m, 1015.09m, 1786.01m,  2607.85m, 2834.74m. Can anyone tell me how I can fix this issue? Maybe my conceptual understanding of Brunt Vaisala is off.

```
el=np.array([75,1015.09,1786.01,2607.85,2834.74])
pres=np.array([945.79,889.87,810.35,732.69,712.33])
temp=np.array([11.27,8.03,7.8,2.09,0.28])
PT=np.array(temp*(1000/pres)**(.286))
BV=metpy.calc.brunt_vaisala_frequency(el*units.meter,PT*units.kelvin)
```

Answer (score 0):

Calculating the Brunt-Vaisala frequency requires taking the vertical derivative of potential temperature with respect to height. Since you are passing in a completely uniform array of heights (as `el`), the value of the vertical derivative is undefined and returned as `nan`. This causes the result of the entire calculation to be returned as `nan` as well.

EDIT FOR UPDATED DATA:

The new data you posted have values of potential temperature that decrease with height. This is by definition an unstable profile and the [Brunt-Vaisala frequency is undefined](https://glossary.ametsoc.org/wiki/Brunt-v%C3%A4is%C3%A4l%C3%A4_frequency) in such cases--so for these values MetPy returns nan.

If you want to see the negative values, you can call `metpy.calc.brunt_vaisala_frequency_squared`, which avoids the problematic square root.

Comment: Hi Dopplershift, thank you so much for your help! I attempted to fix this problem by measuring pressure and temp and 5 different increasing elevations. Now I have five values of potential temp, which are decreasing while elevation increases. These values replaced my "el" array and "PT" array. I hoped that this would fix the issue but I am still receiving NaN for my BV frequency. Can you help?

Comment: Please edit your post above to include a current version of the code with the new values as you're running it and I'll see if I can reproduce the problem.

Comment: I've updated my answer above.